# I have installed a Node.js server on my PC, but I can't connect to the server from another device. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('hello\n');
});

const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Sunucu çalışıyor: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

(node.js)When I try it on my computer with Google, the message "hello" appears on the screen, but on my phone, it says "this site can't be reached." Why is this happening, and if you don't have time to answer, where can I learn more about it?

Comment: By "Google", you mean their Chrome browser?

Comment: How are you trying to reach the server from your phone? Are they connected to the same network? What hostname/address are you using?

Answer (score 0):

well first of all the server is only accessible from your local network however, there are a few ways to make it accessible to anyone e.g you could use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) download it sign up, and start a tunnel from CMD